# Create Scene programmatically (ViewGroup with one TextView)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-transitions

I usually prefer to work with classes instead of XML.

Now this is the ordinary way of creating a scene:

```
TransitionInflater inflater = TransitionInflater.from(this);

ViewGroup mSceneRoot = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.sceneRoot);
Scene mScene2 = Scene.getSceneForLayout(mSceneRoot, R.layout.transition_event,this);

TransitionManager mTransitionManager = inflater.inflateTransitionManager(R.anim.transitions_mgr, mSceneRoot);
mTransitionManager.transitionTo(mScene2);
```

Pretty neat. Since the `R.layout.transition_event` is only a TextView, it creates the following layouts. LinearLayout is the root.

[image]

For making things happen programmatically we can use the `Scene(ViewGroup sceneRoot, ViewGroup layout)` constructor instead of `Scene.getSceneForLayout(..)`.

My problem is the `ViewGroup layout` parameter. Since I want to have only one textview, if I create a FrameLayout and add the textview **this will create an extra view as the above screenshot** which is not the same.

**I either need something like `<merge/>` but programmatically or "convert" TextView into a ViewGroup.**

Here is my best try so far:

```
# I try to do the equivalent of .getSceneForLayout() here
ViewGroup vg = new ViewGroup(MainActivity.this) {
    @Override
     protected void onLayout(boolean b, int i, int i2, int i3, int i4) {
     }
};

TextView tv = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
tv.setText("YOLO!");
vg.addView(tv,0);

mScene2 = new Scene(mSceneRoot, vg);
```

Which btw produces:

[image]

No sure if worths the hustle but I want to figure this out.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `Scene`, but you should probably just add your `TextView` to a subclass of `ViewGroup` (i.e. `LinearLayout` because `TextView` is not a `ViewGroup`.

Comment: @Jakar Yes this works but it's not the optimal solution. It will create an extra view between the `sceneRoot` and the TextView which doesn't happen when inflating a layout.

Comment: Does that create any problems if there's an extra view? You could try `new Scene(root,null).getSceneRoot().addView(new TextView(context) );` You may get a `NullPointerExcetion`, though. From looking at the docs, I don't think you can just add the `TextView` as the `ViewGroup layout` unless passing null works